# My job didn't inform me the hospital called to tell me my husband was admitted. Can I take action against them?

Tags: united-states, human-resources, legal

My husband starting feeling sick at work around 9am. His boss let him leave. He went to urgent care, and from there he was taken to the hospital. When he was admitted, the nurse let him know that she called my job to inform me  he was in the hospital. No one from my job informed me. I went home and started to worry when my husband wasn't coming home from work. I didn't find out until 9pm. Is there anything I can do?

I'm in Illinois. Dupage County, in the Chicago suburbs. I haven't asked yet why I wasn't informed. I missed work the next two days. I'm hoping to get more information before I go into work tomorrow. I will be asking then.

Comment: This sounds like too much of a legal question for this site, but... What do you hope to gain here? If your goal is to get someone fired, going through a lawsuit for that probably isn't worth it (but it would be for you, I don't know). If your goal is a cash settlement, that usually comes down to attaching some monetary value to any distress cause by negligence - I can't imagine you'd get a lot unless e.g. your husband passed away before you managed to get there. Then there's also the question of how easily reachable you are and whether you can even sue the company or just the one responsible.

Comment: Don't forget the whole "innocent until proven guilty" thing.  It's sort of important in US law.  Even if the failure to deliver the message *was* deliberate *and* malicious, and even if there IS a law you can reasonably say they broke, *you still have to prove they broke that law.*  If all you've got is "I didn't receive the message" then you haven't actually *proven* any wrongdoing.

Comment: What "action" are you hoping to achieve? A lawsuit? Get someone fired? Is your husband worse off because of your absence?

Comment: The OP, I think, just wants to know what happened. It is reasonable to feel that way and to make some inquiries. If whoever answered the call fumbled the response, it might be good for them to revisit how to handle such calls-- they do happen sometimes. (though it might be rare now that almost everyone has mobile phones)

Comment: @Dukeling The OP needs to state whether her husband required her consent for some major, life saving surgery, procedure, or otherwise. If that is the case, then I think she would have claim. Also, the question of why her husband gave a work number instead of a direct cell number? Is OP unable to use a cell phone at work?

Comment: Those who closed this question: Pray tell, where are the company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies?  Where is the request for legal advice?

Comment: @Kyralessa I think people feel that is implied from the title part *Can I take action against them?*. My first reaction too. It mismatches the rest of the actual question text.

Comment: *Is there anything I can do?* What is your goal? Please edit that into your question. Otherwise it is too broad ("What should I do" questions are generally closed here). And see the other comments about this being a legal question or not. And is *I missed work the next two days* relevant to the incident of not being called?

Comment: Also: *I'm hoping to get more information before I go into work tomorrow. I will be asking then.* Any updates on what actually happened?

Answer (score 19):

At the moment you don't know *why* this happened.  There are many possibilities:

- Someone who hates you got the message and ignored it.
- Someone got the message, wrote it down, but forgot to give it to you.
- Someone got the message, was on his/her way to your desk to deliver it, but then got interrupted and forgot.
- Someone got the message and sent you an e-mail, but due to some glitch the e-mail didn't get delivered, or the user was offline, or some such.

Upsetting as this is, do you want to go in angry and jeopardize your job over it?

It would be best to start by assuming it was a mistake rather than a deliberate decision by anyone.  If you feel the need to investigate nonetheless, make it as casual as you can.  Perhaps talk to your boss: "It's strange, the hospital said they left a message here, but somehow I never got it..."  Give them a chance to explain.

By the way, I'd say the hospital screwed up too.  They didn't talk to *you*, so they didn't have any way of knowing whether you'd gotten the message.  At least they could have left you the message at home as well as at work.

**EDIT:**  One thing that just occurred to me:

Due to [HIPAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act), the hospital was probably not at liberty to say much of anything about why they were calling.  They certainly couldn't mention your husband's condition, and they might not even have felt it was legally proper to mention his name.

It's quite possible that all they said was something extremely generic like "Please have [regina] call [XYZ Hospital] as soon as she can."  It's likely that the people you work with quite reasonably had no idea the message had much importance or real urgency.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly doubt that anyone intentionally avoided informing you. In all likelihood, there was some miscommunication, either the nurse called the wrong place or someone told someone else to pass a message along and they failed to do so out of forgetfulness.

Going into work looking for revenge is going to end poorly for you. I strongly recommend that you consider this an honest mistake on someone's part.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I don't know what it would take to forget to tell somebody that their husband has been admitted to hospital. That is a "stand up and find them" type message.

Comment: @user1666620 what if they left a voicemail that nobody received? What if it's the nurse that made the mistake and intended to call, but had to deal with another emergency and forgot? What if they called the wrong office?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the nurse did in fact call your place of work, you now know the quality of the people you work for.

So you need to ask yourself - are these the kinds of people that deserve you? Because you sure as hell know how much they value you.

Polish the CV and move on.

Comment: This answer is making a lot of assumptions. We don't know who answered the call at the OP's workplace, we don't know if they did indeed try reaching the OP. Jumping to conclusions like that and taking extreme measures like looking for another job when OP doesn't even know what went wrong is bad advice.

Comment: @MaskedMan maybe I'm wrong, but I get incredibly angry when I hear of employers abusing their staff.

Comment: @user1666620 We don't know whether the *employer* had anything to do with this. Sometimes this sort of thing is a failing by one individual, not a reflection of company attitudes: http://www.askamanager.org/2017/09/my-employee-didnt-give-a-coworker-the-message-that-his-wife-was-in-surgery-and-now-everyone-hates-him.html

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent, whether it's a failure of one individual or the company policy, it doesn't matter, this is something that should be brought to attention.

Comment: @teego1967 Agreed, but I'm not sure what that has to do with anything I said.

Comment: Quitting your job because the receptionist didn't check voicemail is pretty extreme.

Comment: We don't know how the OP work structure is like. Maybe she is out in the field or with customers, and the caller couldn't reach her and then forgot to follow up due to other tasks. Plus, why did the OP's husband gave his wife's work number instead of something direct like a cell or home phone?